# Wyswig editor not showing to authors in Full HTML mode for Authors

Tags: users, input-formats, wysiwyg

I am using wyswig with tinymce 3.5 for my drupal site.
The editor is not working for Authors in FULL HTML mode.it is not showing any action after changing it to plain text or full html.

I have rebuilded permissions also tried [Full Html Text format (and wysiwyg) show only for administrator role](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51530) this solution, cleared cache but its not showing for the authors.
Not able to resolve whether it is permission issue or js.

Also this issue is came after i am using book access module.
Check image for reference.[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved as it is js error.
I fixed this issue from this solution(https://drupal.org/comment/6313896#comment-6313896).

As i am using wyswig 7.x-2.1 but the above fix is given for 7.x-2.0 which is applied clearly for my version too.
The below fig. shows that the js error.

[image]